# properly sort a file contents by its e-value containing column

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I want to sort contents of a tab delimited file based on a column of e-values (3rd column from last) like which is performed in excel. My file is like:

```
or1|306502419   or1|306502419   100 1175    0   0   1   1175    1   1175    1.10E-18    2381.7  100
or1|306502428   or1|306502428   100 704 0   0   1   704 1   704 1.10E-22    1354    100
or1|306502451   or1|306502451   100 1039    0   0   1   1039    1   1039    1.10E-918   2081.2  100
or1|306502451   or2|315578614   99.1    1039    9   0   1   1039    1   1039    6.70E-296   2065.8  100
or1|306502443   or1|306502443   100 551 0   0   1   551 1   551 6.20E-297   1100.9  100
or1|306502365   or1|306502365   100 620 0   0   1   620 1   620 0   1221.1  100
or1|306502365   or3|315163411   99.7    620 2   0   1   620 1   620 0   1219.1  100
or1|306502371   or3|315163404   100 590 0   0   1   590 1   590 0   1209.5  100
or1|306502371   or1|306502371   100 590 0   0   1   590 1   590 0   1209.5  100
or1|306502380   or1|306502380   100 560 0   0   1   560 1   560 1.10E-10    1113.6  100
or1|306502380   or3|315163395   98.9    560 6   0   1   560 1   560 1.10E-14    1098.2  100
```

I have tried:

```
d_list = [line.strip() for line in open("input_file.txt")]
d_list.sort(key = lambda line: line.split("\t")[-3])
for line in d_list:
   print line
```

But the sorted e-values are :

```
0
0
0
0
1.10E-10
1.10E-14
1.10E-18
1.10E-22
1.10E-918
6.70E-296
6.20E-297
```

But I want them to be:

```
0
0
0
0
1.10E-918
6.20E-297
6.70E-296
1.10E-22
1.10E-18
1.10E-14
1.10E-10
```

plz note that I have also tried

> reverse = True

flag in line2 but it place low e-value upward rather than 0s.

Plz suggest.
Thanks for your consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting them as strings, not as numbers. You need to cast the e-values to a number first. From the looks of it, `float` precision won't be enough for you (1.10E-918 will become 0.0), so you can use `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
d_list.sort(key = lambda line: Decimal(line.split("\t")[-3]))
```